# Bootstrap and text align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i text align items in a DIV, that is in a row, to the top but at the same time align the entire div in the center of the section. ?

I am able to align all text to the top, but once I add a center class for the div, it cancels out the text alignment

Below you can see I have added *align-top* which aligns the DIVs to the top, but how can i add a styling that makes the whole div center of page? i assumed it would be done automatically because of the column widths

Please help me solve this, thank you

```
<!-- Services Section Start -->
<section id="services" class="section center-block" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="section-header" id="#services">
            <h2 class="section-title">ABOUT US</h2>
            <hr class="lines wow zoomIn" id="lines">
            <p class="section-subtitle wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="0.3s">We are the Mother City’s top choice for tailor-made holistic treatment plans that empower you to take – and maintain - control of your own health and fertility. Our holistic approach offers you a range of complementary therapies, alongside the best of what conventional medicine has to offer globally, on your personalized path to parenthood.</p>
            <br>
        </div>
        **<div class="row col-md-12 top align-top">**
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 row item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                <div class="col-md-3 row">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i><img src="img/icons/setsusapart.png"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <p><b>For Egg & Sperm Recipients</b></p>
                    <p>When you’re not one of the lucky ones who can take fertility for granted, having your child could be difficult, or even impossible, without the help of a donor. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 row item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                <div class="col-md-3 row">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><i><img src="img/icons/our-facilities.png"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <p><b>Become an Egg Donar</b></p>
                    <p>A primary goal is to improve quality of life during and after treatment, and to facilitate a space for reflection on the diagnoses and/or treatment cycles that are recommended.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 row item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
                <div class="col-md-3 row">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i><img src="img/icons/setsusapart.png"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <p><b>For Egg & Sperm Recipients</b></p>
                    <p>When you’re not one of the lucky ones who can take fertility for granted, having your child could be difficult, or even impossible, without the help of a donor. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Services Section End -->
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on how you want? Adding an reference or create  a fiddle?

Comment: Don't nest `row` directly inside `row`, and `row` shouldn't be used on the same div as `col-*`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i completely understand your problem, but Did you try make this div margin: auto for this "time align the entire div in the center of the section."

If you give any div width declared width/max-width other than auto then you can center it with margin: auto; like here in you want make only horizontal center

```
.your-div{
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or if you want vertical and horizontal centering your div.

```
.your-div{
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: i applied this class to the div, and it shifted more left, but what im trying to say and sorry for my terrible explanation, is that: simply put, the div is not spanned across the entire section width, even when i specify col-md-12.

Comment: i gave the container a width and applied the styling you provided and this seemed to work, so thank you! But if you could just tell me why the div would not be automatically centered if it is created in bootsrap and the div is inside of a section that is already centered aligned?

Comment: This not gonna be the best solution, but maybe try make this like me: https://codepen.io/mzadrozny/pen/pVRXWV you can change this to justify-content: space-around to make even more center;

Comment: i'm not bootstrap expert, but maybe because you give this col-12 to row, but in bootstrap documentation its seems to be col-12 in a row like here:

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: so first div width class row and the in it div width class col-12